# Jquery validation,submithandler does not work

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do some additional checks and formatting on certain fields of my form before it is submitted. Hence I used the bassistance jquery validation plugin. It works well as it displays all the manadatory error messages properly, however as soon as I supply the necessary values, the form simply submits. At this point I am not even sure if `submitHandler` is even triggered. Any ideas?

Form html: http://jsfiddle.net/7PAZU/

```
$(function() {
    $("#commentForm").validate({
        rules: {
            bill_first_name: {
                required: true
            },
            bill_last_name: {
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            Phone: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            },

            bill_address_one: {
                required: true
            },
            bill_city: {
                required: true
            },
            bill_state_or_province: {
                required: true
            },
            charge_total: {
                required: true,
                float: true
            },
        },
        messages: {
            bill_first_name: {
                required: "Please put in First Name"
            },
            bill_last_name: {
                required: "Please put in last Name"
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please enter a valid email"
            },
            phone: {
                required: "Please enter a valid Phone Number"

            },

            bill_address_one: {
                required: "Please put in Address"
            },
            bill_city: {
                required: "Please put in  City"
            },
            bill_state_or_province: {
                required: "Please put in state"
            },
            charge_total: {
                required: "Please put Amount In Whole number such as 10.00",
                number: "Please put in Amount In Whole number such as 10.00"
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function(frm) {
            $("#charge_total").val(parseFloat($("#charge_total").val()).toFixed(2));
            alert("Dukhche Na");
            return false;
        }
    });
})​
```

Comment: does your javascript console reports any error on form submit?

Comment: You have extra commas for a start - this will cause problems in IE

Comment: I use firebug and no it does'nt

Comment: Can you include your HTML ? and to confirm there are no errors on the page ? perhaps your form doesnt have the correct ID and this isnt even binding ?

Comment: @user734081, check my answer, it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is failing because you are using a validation rule that does not exist.

```
charge_total: {
                required: true,
                float: true // there's no validator named `float`
            } // Comma removed here
```

But there is no validator named `float` in that plugin. Remove that and it will work fine. You can create a custom `float` validator if you want.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/7PAZU/1/)

Check list of available rules here http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Validator

**How did I find this?**

I checked the console and found this error being thrown

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
```

From the following line inside plugin source file

```
var result = $.validator.methods[method]
      .call( this, element.value.replace(/\r/g, ""), element, rule.parameters );
```

Meaning `$.validator.methods[method]` is undefined which proves that you are using a validator that does not exist.

So I Checked available validation methods list and `your rules` and found you are using `float` rule which is not available.

So JS is throwing this error and stopping execution, so your `submit handler` is not being called and form is being submitted(Which is the default behavior unless you prevent that using `JS`).

Answer (score 2):

IE is particularly picky with extra commas ... remove them for a start :

```
$(function() {
    $("#commentForm").validate({
        rules: {
            bill_first_name: {
                required: true
            },
            bill_last_name: {
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            Phone: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            },

            bill_address_one: {
                required: true
            },
            bill_city: {
                required: true
            },
            bill_state_or_province: {
                required: true
            },
            charge_total: {
                required: true,
                float: true
            } // Comma removed here
        },
        messages: {
            bill_first_name: {
                required: "Please put in First Name"
            },
            bill_last_name: {
                required: "Please put in last Name"
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please enter a valid email"
            },
            phone: {
                required: "Please enter a valid Phone Number"

            },

            bill_address_one: {
                required: "Please put in Address"
            },
            bill_city: {
                required: "Please put in  City"
            },
            bill_state_or_province: {
                required: "Please put in state"
            },
            charge_total: {
                required: "Please put Amount In Whole number such as 10.00",
                number: "Please put in Amount In Whole number such as 10.00"
            } // Comma removed here
        },
        submitHandler: function(frm) {
            $("#charge_total").val(parseFloat($("#charge_total").val()).toFixed(2));
            alert("Dukhche Na");
            return false;
        }
    });
})​
```

Comment: +1 Most probably comma will be the error...i faced this sitn many times

Comment: @user734081 can you include the `form` html in the question ? does it definately have an id of `commentForm` ?

Comment: @ManseUK yes it does have same id, and the validation rules work in general, the problem seems to be with submitHandler only